Android setting "remove animations" breaks my app.. is there a way for an app to opt out?
I have word game (Upwords) that is a Scrabble like game. When a user places a tile I glow the letter tiles that form words green or red to indicate if the word is in the dictionary or not.
Some users are complaining it's not working.. I just discovered that those users have enabled "remove animations" in the Settings app in Accessibility.
Is there any way for an app or a particular animation call to opt out of this system wide setting?  Or, at minimum, detect if it's enabled so I can alert the user
